Why aren't there approximation signs before some of the values in this table?
Why aren't there approximation signs (~) before some of the values in this table?

This list is from Physics for Scientists and Engineers, 5th edition, by Serway and Beichner.

Those aren't approximation signs, they refer to the order of magnitude

@gandalf61 That should be an answer instead of a comment.

@VincentThacker Well, yes, I would make it an answer if only people didn't keep closing this entirely clear and reasonable question.

@gandalf61 When I made that comment it was open. I agree with you and have voted to reopen.

The question isn't "why are there", it's "why aren't there".

Simply because they are orders of magnitude and not approximations in the strict sense of the term. The masses of the objects we are pretty sure, e.g. electron are given exactly. It doesn't matter how you get the electron Or anything. The approx. sign before others refers that they depend on the individuals. However, finding the mass of observable universe is something out of context.

" finding the mass of observable universe is something out of context." why is that?

Coz, how are you expected to calculate mass of observable universe? You can merely speculate it. Mass, is something which has driven scientists crazy for a long time and does that even now.

but they surely get the number by observatons and calculation, not speculation. It is the visible universe for once.

What is the observable universe now is not the observable universe for the next second. I hope that clears my point. Other points from my previous comment are also pretty powerful.

great explanation, thanks.

(Turning my comment into an answer now that the question has been reopened)
Assuming these values are for mass in kg, the values for horse, human, frog etc. cannot be more precise because they depend so much on the individual horse, human, frog etc. Other figures are given to the precision that they are known (one significant figure in the case of the mass of the Milky Way) apart from the mass of the visible Universe, which is presumably not even known to one significant figure.

The electron mass is known to 9 significant figures. https://pml.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?me|search_for=electron+mass
